# how can I reformat a single column of a csv file with sed or awk

Tags: csv, awk, sed

how can I reformat a single column with awk or sed?

currently I get the following output:

```
"11002","","","None","172.16.10.1","udp","53","DNS Server Detection","A DNS server is listening on the remote host.","The remote service is a Domain Name System (DNS) server, which
provides a mapping between hostnames and IP addresses.","Disable this service if it is not needed or restrict access to
internal hosts only if the service is available externally.","http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System",""
```

but I want to have the entire output in a single line:

```
"11","","","No","10.1.1.1","udp","53","DNS","A DNS ","remote IP","Disable","Domain_Name_System",""
```

Comment: Can you please clarify how the initial output is transformed to the desired output? What are the rules?

Answer (score 1):

Neither awk nor sed is well-suited to handling CSV files in general. Of course you may be lucky, but it might be worthwhile adding a CSV-aware tool to your arsenal.  If you don't want to rely on a spreadsheet program, you could do worse than rely on a strategy summarized by: csv2tsv | MUNGE | tsv2csv.

There are, in fact, command-line tools named csv2tsv and tsv2csv available freely, and several Perl CSV-parsing solutions are well-known.  PHP has a very handy function, fgetcsv, and it's easy to write a wrapper around that.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;N;s/^([^"\n]*("[^"\n]*"[^"\n]*)*"[^"\n]*)\n/\1/;ta;P;D' file
```

This removes newlines inbetween double quotes. The solution is however fragile and does not cater for quoted double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to boil down to finding a possibility to discriminate between line breaks that are part of your text columns and line breaks that really mark the end of a CSV line. 
You ask specifically for `awk` or `sed`. But since this implies that you most probably have `tr` available as well, try this:

```
cat your.csv | sed 's/"$/"#/' | tr "\n" " " | tr "#" "\n"
```

I assumed that a `"` as last char on a line is probably the ending quote of a CSV line's last field. If you have spaces there you could throw in a `sed 's/ *$//'`. Furthermore I assumed that you don't have any `#` chars in your file, since I used it to mark "real" line endings. If this is not the case you'd have to find another unused character for that purpose.